# Need help on generic array creation

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I have a line of code which compiles and works:

```
HashMap<String, Object>[] resultArray = 
        new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap[].class);
```

It uses [Jackson ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.net.URL,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference)).

And I have another line, which gives `Generic array creation error`:

```
HashMap<String, Object>[] resultArray = new HashMap<String, Object>[] { resultObject };
```

I know that it is not possible to do this in Java. But obviously `readValue()` somehow did it. How can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readValue created an array of the raw type, `HashMap[]` -- not of `HashMap<String, Object>[]`. Raw types are a relatively low-level, mostly-obsolete feature that you should try to avoid if possible; but with certain things, like reflection (which Jackson relies on heavily), it's often not possible.

The short of it is that Jackson is playing with a dangerous tool. As with many dangerous tools, it's not that it'll *always* cause damage; it's that it *can* cause damage, and should thus be used carefully and with some amount of experience.

The danger essentially boils down to the fact that with raw types, the compiler can't track the actual, parameterized types you want to work with; and that means it can't protect you from using them incorrectly.

At some point, you'll probably be casting this raw array to a generic one; something like:

```
HashMap[] original = new HashMap[0];
HashMap<String,Object>[] publiclyVisible = original;
// or
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String,Object> singleElement = original[0];
```

Because of [erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), there's actually nothing in the JVM that can track that `publiclyVisible` is meant to hold an array of `HashMap<String, Object>`s. All the JVM knows is that it holds an array of raw `HashMap`s. Thus, if you put a `Map<Integer, Foo>` into `original`, the JVM will let you; and if someone later retrieves it as a `Map<String, Object>`, the JVM will happily allow that, too. It's only when someone tries to *use* the types that they'll get into trouble, and it'll be at a very non-obvious way. For instance, maybe they'll do:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = publiclyVisible[0];
for (String key : myMap.keySet()) {
    ...
```

... and they'll get a ClassCastException on that `for` line, saying that Integer can't be cast to String. This is very confusing! The problem is that the JVM has erased the type information, such that it couldn't track any of the improper array stuff. The first time it detects something is amiss is when it casts the reference of the first `myMap` key — which is an Integer, because this was accidentally a `HashMap<Integer, Foo>` — to a String. Essentially, the programmer expects `myMap`'s keys to all be Strings, but erasure and raw types have conspired to allow them to be any type at all.

There are other variants of the problem, and other confusing ways to trigger it; but they all boil down to the same basic problem. In short, erasure means that the JVM can't track the actual types of your references, and raw types means the compiler can't track them either, and when you combine those them you can increase the likelihood of a confusing bug.

Comment: What damage can it cause?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer Ah thanks, I'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: Is it about unchecked assignments?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer Essentially, yes. :)